# Assigning a value by checking a box in razor pages

Tags: asp.net-core, checkbox, web-applications, razor-pages

I`m making a web app for online exams and after i write the question and the answers, i want to select the right answer by checking a checkbox. [The right answer][1] will have the same value as the checked answer but i do not know how to make it appear in the [question list][2] or in the [database][3].

Model variables:

```
public string question{get;set;}
public string asnwer1{get;set;}
public string answer2{get;set;}
public string answer3{get;set;}
public string answer4{get;set;}
public string rightanswer{get;set;}
```

Create question page cshtml:

> Intrebare = Question | Optiune = Answer | Raspuns = Right Answer.

```
<div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="text-danger"></span>
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input id="Checkbox1"  type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
        <div class="form-group">
            <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="control-label"></label>
            <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="form-control" />
            <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="text-danger"></span>
            <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
        </div>
```

Thank you!
[1]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/MRUqr.png
[2]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/sgnst.png
[3]:https://i.stack.imgur.com/ztIIc.png

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to bind Raspuns when the checkbox is checked,you can add a hidden input with `asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Raspuns"`,and before posting form,iterate div with `class="form-group"`,then check if the check box in the div is checked.If so,set the hidden input value with the input's value in the div.Here is a demo:

cshtml:

```
<form method="post" id="myform">

    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Intrebare" class="text-danger"></span>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune1" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input id="Checkbox1" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune2" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input id="Checkbox2" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune3" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input id="Checkbox3" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="control-label"></label>
        <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="form-control" />
        <span asp-validation-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Optiune4" class="text-danger"></span>
        <input id="Checkbox4" type="checkbox" />
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="submit" />
    <input asp-for="AplicatieIntrebare.Raspuns" hidden />
</form>
@section scripts {
    <script>
        $("#myform").submit(function () {
            $(".form-group").each(function (index, element) {
                if ($(element).children("input[type='checkbox']").prop("checked")) {
                    $("#AplicatieIntrebare_Raspuns").attr("value", $(element).children("input[type='text']").val());
                }
                
            })
        })
    </script> 
}
```

cshtml.cs:

```
[BindProperty]
        public AplicatieIntrebare AplicatieIntrebare { get; set; }
        public void OnGet()
        {
            AplicatieIntrebare = new AplicatieIntrebare { Intrebare = "What's my dog's name?", Optiune1 = "Jerry", Optiune2 = "Spot", Optiune3 = "Rex", Optiune4 = "Max" };
        }
        public void OnPost()
        {
            
        }
```

result:

[image]